# Do I need a new keystore when I create a new version for my app in android?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

My app already in the play store. I made a few changes in my app and want to update it in the play store.

So do I need a new keystore when I create a new version of my app? or I can use with the same old one from the previous version(code)?

Thank you

Comment: No, use your old keystore and password

Comment: Protect your old keystore with a cost of your life. You will not be able to upload an update if you loose it. You can upload an update only if you sign it with the same key in same keystore

Answer (score 4):

You must use the same key !
Otherwise GPlay is not sure you are the same person who pushed the first version of that app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your old keystore and update your version code and version name to update your app on play store and also database version if you are using sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

Keystores are for to keep keys inside of it like a safe box. You have to use same key for same application. Think of it this way, a key as a signature of yours that you sign your application as a proof of that you did that application.